# What's an effective way to make sure I'm prepared for an online aptitude test while applying for a job?

Tags: recruitment, test

I just got an invitation to participate in an online psychometric test (the first step of the recruitment process in the company where I applied).

I'm worried. I feel nervous and am scared that I will go blank when I'm doing the online test.

What's an effective way to make sure I'm prepared so that I can stop being worried and do well on the test?

Comment: What is the nature of the test? Video interview? Written? Multiple choice?

Comment: What post/designation you had applied for? What discipline/topic the test will be on?

Comment: ... with as few specifics as you've given, there's not much more we can tell you than any advice you could get from googling 'How to do well on a test'.

Comment: _[Questions require a goal that we can address](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/). Rather than explaining the difficulties of your situation, explain what you want to do to make it better. For more information, [see this meta post](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2696/61983)._

Comment: @MatthewGaiser multiple choice

Comment: Can they tell you the purpose of that test? For instance, is it going to be a personality test? A math test? a technical test? Also, can they tell you the platform it's going to be on? Maybe, you could practice in advance to get used to the platform.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk math and personality , i think it will gonna be use SHL test like the info i get from email

Comment: SHL? You have to stop assuming we know what you're talking about.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk sry i mean this one https://www.assessmentday.co.uk/shl.htm

Comment: I am voting to reopen as well, but the question needs to be updated for the specific industry.

Comment: Now, you need to tell us for what kind of job this is for. For instance, if you're a salesman they'll want someone who is outgoing. But one time, I interviewed for an inspector type of position, and previous inspectors had become too friendly with the workers at the worksites they were inspecting, so they were looking for an introverted person that new time around.

Comment: This is to say also your mind won't go blank. This is NOT a knowledge test. This is a preference test. You just pick what you prefer. That's it. Usually, the same type of questions are asked again and again, but in slightly different ways or in various different degrees. So you just go through them one at a time. But like I said, you have to know what type of job you're applying for. Because if you can figure out what type of personality they're looking for, it doesn't take a genius to figure out how to answer the questions the way a person with that personality would answer those questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> any tips on doing the online test? so im not nervous or get blank when
>   i do it the test

Find out ahead of time what service is used for the online test. Many sites offer free trials and/or practice tests - not the actual questions you will face, but a way to get familiar with the interface, the timing, etc.

From your comments, it appears the company is AssessmentDay. They have a 24-hour free trial at https://www.assessmentday.co.uk/member/signup/free-trial

Give that a try, and be as prepared as you can with the job-related material that will likely be part of the questions. Do a bit of reading and cramming.

Answer (score 3):

It is a norm these days to conduct online tests as one of the filtering criteria.

Going blank could happen while attempting for the first time. Be prepared for it and take a bold step. It could be possible that the questions could be something you are able to answer. If you cannot, then take it as a learning. This experience would definitely come handy for your next stint.

As far as tips are concerned, there are a few websites that conduct such mock tests. Try those; they are quite helpful.